# What is the smallest integer $n$ for which $\theta(n) > n$?

Tags: number-theory

What is the smallest integer $n$ for which $\theta(n) > n$? Here $\theta(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} \log p$.

I googled around, checked some likely textbooks, and ran a program for $n \leq 10^7$, but didn't find it.

The integer and a reference would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, assuming there is such a thing. The first number for which $\mbox{Li} x$ and $\pi(x)$ change places is almost $10^{400}$

Comment: @RClark Wikipedia has some good information on the number Will refers to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27_number

Comment: @MatthewConroy: Thanks, I found that.

Comment: @WillJagy Such a number does exist by Littlewood's Oscillation Theorem for $\theta(x)$.

Comment: This function is most commonly written $\vartheta$ with `\vartheta`.